# How does EF check if the database is latest version?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I know EF checks the EdmMetadata table to determine if the version of model classes is same as database tables.

I want to know exactly how EF can find if the version of a model has changed. In other words, I want to know what does EF compare to the modelhash in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [blog post](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/04/08/code-first-what-is-that-edmmetadata-table/) about the EdmMetadata table.

For your question, this is the relevant parts:

> The EdmMetadata table is a simple way for Code First to tell if the
>   model used to create a database is the same model that is now being
>   used to access the database. As of EF 4.1 the only thing stored in the
>   table is a single row containing a hash of the SSDL part of the model
>   used to create the database.
>
> (Geek details: when you look in an EDMX file, the SSDL is the part of
>   that file that represents the database (store) schema. This means that
>   the EdmMetadata model hash only changes if the database schema that
>   would be generated changes; changes to the conceptual model (CSDL) or
>   the mapping between the conceptual model and the database (MSL) will
>   not affect the hash.)